# Rails exporting xls using link_to format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hello everybody who likes RAILS, i have a problem i'm trying to export by "ejecutive_id" to XLS but i'm not doing the correct code,

```
  -I created a select box where i can select all my ejecutives.
  -I created another select box where i can select by status_id.
  -I selected 1 ejecutive for example "Mogan"   (ejecutive_id = 1)
  -I selected 1 status form example "active"   (status_id = 0 )
  -After selecting both select boxes i click on "SEARCH"
  -After doing SEARCH i'm getting my results  (@list_policies this value in my code is before respond format)
```

Here is my controller

```
 ****PROJECT/APP/CONTROLLER/policy_managment/policy.rb********

class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController

 def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial 

        @search_ejecutive = params[:search_ejecutive]
        @search_status = params[:status_id]

        @list_ejecutives_comision = Ejecutive.find(:all)
        @list_policies_search = Policy.deleted_is(0)

        if params[:search_ejecutive].to_i!=0
           @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.ejecutive_id_is(@search_ejecutive)
        end

        if !params[:status_id].blank?
            if params[:status_id].to_i != 3
                  @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.state_is(params[:status_id])
            end
        else
            @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.state_is(0)
        end

        @status_id = params[:status_id]

        if !@search_dependent_dni.blank?
          if @list_dependents.blank?
            @list_dependents = Dependent.id_gt(0)
          end

          @list_dependents = @list_dependents.num_document_is(@search_dependent_dni)

          list_dependencies = []
          @list_dependents.each do |dependent|
                list_dependency_dependents = Dependency.find(:all, :conditions => { :dependent_id => dependent.id })
                list_dependency_dependents.each do |dependency|
                    list_dependencies << dependency
                end
          end

           policy_ids = []
            list_dependencies.each do |dependency|
                policy_ids << dependency.policy_id.to_i
            end

        end

        @list_policies_search = @list_policies_search.deleted_is(0)
        @list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) 
                @results = @list_policies_search.find(:all,:conditions=> { :ejecutive_id => @search_ejecutive }) 

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.xls
            format.js {
                render :update do |page|
                   page.replace_html 'table', :partial => 'table2'
                end
            }
        end
  end
 end
```

Here maybe could be the problem,also those are my links where i can export

```
     *********HERE IS MY VIEW***********
     <% form_remote_tag :url=>{:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial"},:before=>"load_close('loading_search')",:success=>"load_off('loading_search')" do -%> 
     <label>EJECUTIVES:</label>
     <%= select_tag 'search_ejecutive',"<option value=\"\">Select</option>"+options_for_select(@list_ejecutives_comision.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]})%>
   </span>
        <label>STATUS :</label>
    <%= select_tag "status_id","<option value=\"3\">ALL</option>"+options_for_select([["active",0],["cancel",1],["no cancel ",2]],0) %>
  </span>

   <input name="Buscar" value="SEARCH" type="submit" /><span id="loading_search"></span>
   <% end %>         


    #HERE WITH THOSE LINKS I'M EXPORTING ONLY MY FIRST 10 VALUES 
   <%= link_to("Export Excel","http://localhost:3000/policy_management/policy/generate_print_ejecutive/generate_print_ejecutive_comercial.xls")%>
   <%= link_to "Export  XLS",:controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial",:format=>"xls"  %>
   <%= link_to 'PRINT PDF', :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :format=>"pdf" %>
```

I'm exporting my partial view and it depends of this

```
   @list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Here is my partial view and i'm using @list_policies

```
 ********************PARTIAL VIEW THAT I WANT TO EXPORT*********
 <table>

  <% @list_policies.each do |policy| %>
   <tr>
     <td><div class="nobreak"><%= policy.num_policy%></div></td>
     <td><div class="nobreak">
  <% if !policy.ejecutive.blank? %>
        <%= policy.ejecutive.name %><%= policy.ejecutive.lastname1 %><%= policy.ejecutive.lastname2 %>
  <% end %></div>
    </td> 
    <td><div class="nobreak"><%= policy.str_state%></div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Seems that i need to add some params to my links_to....format.... i don't know what to add
Somebody can check this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

It seems like using an options hash to dynamically build your query might be easier / cleaner.  I would do it like this:

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController

  def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial

    @list_ejecutives_comision = Ejecutive.find(:all)

    policy_options = {:deleted => false}
    policy_options = policy_options.merge({:ejecutive_id => params[:search_ejecutive]}) unless params[:search_ejecutive].blank?
    policy_options = policy_options.merge({:state => params[:status_id]}) unless params[:status_id].blank? and (params[:status_id] != 3)
    @list_policies_search = Policy.all(policy_options)

    if !@search_dependent_dni.blank?
      if @list_dependents.blank?
        @list_dependents = Dependent.id_gt(0)
      end

      @list_dependents = @list_dependents.num_document_is(@search_dependent_dni)

      list_dependencies = []
      @list_dependents.each do |dependent|
        list_dependency_dependents = Dependency.find(:all, :conditions => { :dependent_id => dependent.id })
        list_dependency_dependents.each do |dependency|
          list_dependencies << dependency
        end 
      end

      policy_ids = []
      list_dependencies.each do |dependency|
        policy_ids << dependency.policy_id.to_i
      end

    end

    @list_policies = @list_policies_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xls
      format.js {
        render :update do |page|
        page.replace_html 'table', :partial => 'table2'
        end 
      } 
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm using rails 2.3.5. Here is this part
   @list_policies_search = Policy.where(policy_options) is not working where how can i do instead of "where" ????

Comment: oh - you might adjust your tags, since they say rails 3.  At any rate, it's the same concept, but your query would instead be ` @list_policies_search = Policy.find(:all, policy_options)`

Comment: Wow...now it says = " Unknown key(s): deleted "  if i remove "policy_options = {:deleted => false}" is showing wrong number of arguments (2 for 1). Please be patient with me i don't know much about it

Comment: start with `policy_options = {}` -- removing the deleted flag for the time being (sorry I haven't used rails 2 in quite a while)

Comment: oh i did a mistake ,your code is working but i'm getting a cycle that never ends....i checked in console and i get this "ArgumentError (Unknown key(s): state, ejecutive_id):
  app/controllers/policy_management/policy_controller.rb:3110:in `generate_print_ejecutive_comercial'"

Comment: well you'll have to adjust the keys for the proper field names, I was guessing based on your code

Comment: Ok but i have a last question about my code  #HERE WITH THOSE LINKS I'M EXPORTING ONLY MY FIRST 10 VALUES 
   <%= link_to("Export Excel","http://localhost:3000/policy_management/policy/generate_print_ejecutive/generate_print_ejecutive_comercial.xls")%>
   <%= link_to "Export  XLS",:controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial",:format=>"xls"  %>
   <%= link_to 'PRINT PDF', :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :format=>"pdf" %> ..........is it correct? or i need to add parameters???

Comment: ok man your code worked!! thank you but is not exporting my partial view, should add something on my links???

Comment: Ae you asking what link you would need to view the current page (which is a partial loaded from the results of a form) in pdf or xls?

Comment: Well I'll explain you here i wrote my partial view according to your ideas my code is working with this ......@results = @list_policies_search.find(:all,:conditions=> { :ejecutive_id => @search_ejecutive }) but my links that i created only are exporting 10 first values

Comment: try removing the pagination.

Comment: i did it and still getting 10 results...something strange is this...seems that i need to add something on my linnks

Comment: can you edit your original question with your updated controller

Comment: your partial (in code listed above) is iterating over @list_policies which is still using pagination.  try iterating over @results instead `<% @results.each do |policy| %>`